# Select XML AJAX document as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

In an HTML document I'm calling for an external JavaScript code (`<script src="...">` in the HMTL) which loads an external .xml file using AJAX:

*Do not analyze `myFunction(xml)` yet. I'm goin to explain it below*

```
var xhttp, xmlDoc, txt, x, i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // Support IE5 and IE6
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         myFunction(this);
    }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "http://sample.com/db.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var EXAMPLE = document.querySelectorAll('product[code="DVR4H1004N1P"]')[0].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML; // Test line 1
    alert(EXAMPLE); // Test line 2
}
```

`myFunction(xml)` explained (now check as I explain):

1. Gets the XML document
2. Changes the content of an element with `id="demo2"` **in the HTML** to the **value** (.nodeValue) of the **first** ([0]) `<price>` element **in the XML**.

The expected result is "94 600", right? And that's what it returns. No errors so far.

But that's not what I truly want, I actually want to change the content of `id="demo2"` **in the HTML** to the value of the `<price>` element inside `<product code="DVR4H1004N1P">` **in the XML**. This should return the same value, "94 600". *Don't ask, I just need to do it this way*.

The closest solution I've done is essentially the third action of `myFunction(xml)`:

3. Defines an "EXAMPLE" variable that refers to the value of the `<price>` element inside `<product code="DVR4H1004N1P">` **in the HTML**.
4. Show in an alert box the value of variable "EXAMPLE", just to see if it's working.

In regards to the third action, the problem is it's looking for the value of `<price>` **in the HTML** and not in the XML. My struggle is I can't figure out **how to access/select the XML document in a variable declaration in JavaScript**.

### Possible "solution"

For example, instead of using `document.querySelectorAll('product[code="DVR4H1004N1P"]')[0].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;` I could point not to the document but the variable that has the XML document (aka "xmlDoc"), like `xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('product[code="DVR4H1004N1P"]')[0].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].innerHTML;`

But it doesn't work. If you need extra info don't hesitate to ask in comments!

Comment: PEOPLE! I got it working just what I said I should do: changing `document.` with `xmlDoc.`. I thought I had tried; maybe I changed something else. If you're a moderator you should close this.

Comment: Oops. Didn't see this :D

Comment: You could have just deleted the question yourself before @philantrovert answered it. If they delete their answer, then you can delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, maybe:

```js
var text = '<catalog><product code="DVR4H1004N1P"><title>DVR de 4 Canales Tribrido (AHD, Análogo y Digital, IP)</title><code>DVR4H1004N1P</code><price>94 600</price></product><product code="DVR81008"><title>DVR de 8 Canales (Full D1, 960H)</title><code>DVR81008</code><price>185 000</price></product></catalog>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(text);
var products = $(xmlDoc).find("product");
var price = products.each(function(i, j){
 if($(j).attr("code") == "DVR4H1004N1P"){
   $("#demo").html(($(j).find("price")[0].innerHTML));
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">
```

Comment: 1Won't really try since I found the solution myself. +1 for answer. What was the purpose of having the original XML as variable and then parsing it, anyways? :)

Comment: @alej27 I had written it before you updated in the comment so I just posted it for the sake of it. Might help anyone. And that variable is just there. XD